# systemd-journal Rate Limit

Tags: linux, journald

I have a service set up on CentOS 7 which outputs *a lot* of log messages, which results in this in the system log / journal: `systemd-journal[xxxx]: Suppressed 864 messages from /system.slice/example.service`.

However, I want to see all of the service messages for debug and diagnostic purposes. Furthermore, I want to disable rate limiting, since this is just a test server.

I've set `RateLimitInterval=0` and `RateLimitBurst=0` in /etc/systemd/journald.conf, but systemd-journal doesn't seem to obey this setting. A `systemctl restart systemd-journald` command or system restart doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions on how to diagnose this? Is there a command to show what configuration systemd-journald is currently using?

Comment: did you reload systemd configuration itself? systemctl daemon-reload

Comment: @DennisNolte, no luck, I even did a `daemon-reload`, `restart systemd-journald`, followed by another `daemon-reload` just to make sure command order wasn't an issue.

Thank you for the suggestion. Please let me know if you come up with anything else.

Comment: I decided to temporarily work around the problem by redirecting the output to a file via the service's ExecStart setting.

Comment: Systemd maintainer stated it's considered to be a bug in *the kernel* if many messages are created in a short interval.

Comment: Would be nice to have logger that focuses on logging instead of going on strike due to "bad working conditions"

Comment: Installed rsyslogd, took out systemd-journald. /etc/rsyslog.conf helpfully had all the necessary "running without journald" configuration commented out, just waiting to be taken into use. Rock solid.

Comment: @JonasBerlin: Can you make your comment about rsyslogd into an answer so I can upvote it? It's been years that this bug/misfeature has been in journald.

Comment: @U.Windl *Systemd maintainer stated it's considered to be a bug in the kernel if many messages are created in a short interval.* LOLWUT?!?!  What is systemd going to do in that case?  Panic the kernel? "Hey, something generated a lot lot log messages!  Must be something wrong with the **KERNEL**!!! Time to panic and crash everything!"  Par for the systemd course, I guess...

Answer (score 0):

As syslog was neither designed to handle very large messages, nor a continuous stream of messages, you should consider writing to a plain text file instead of using syslog services.

This is specifically true if the "messages" are debug-type of messages.

Also "rate limiting" can mean two different things:

- The number of message you *want* to output
- the number of messages you *can* output

The manual of journald.conf explains:

> If, in the time interval defined by `RateLimitIntervalSec=`, more messages than specified in `RateLimitBurst=` are logged by a service, all further messages within the interval are dropped until the interval is over.

So obviously you want to make `RateLimitIntervalSec` rather small (like 1 second), while making `RateLimitBurst` rather large (like several millions, assuming the system can handle a syslog message within less than one microsecond).